# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT for Google Maps API - php to client side

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, limit, geocoding, client-side

We are connecting to http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml using a PHP script to geocode a postcode into lon/lat. We are finding that we are constantly hitting the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status. even though we are storing the postcodes for 1 day.

I would like to look at client side geocoding, but wasn't sure to do it exactly. please can someone take a look at this and see how best to re-write this so that we don't hit the overlimit.

Thanks

```
<?php
//database and connection are defined elsewhere
mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

  //check if postcode exists in database

  $sqlTS1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `postcodestable` WHERE `postcode` = UPPER('" . $_GET['postcode'] . "') AND `date_added` >  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
  if(mysql_num_rows($sqlTS1)>0) {}
  else
  {     

        $postcodeTS1 = strtoupper($_GET['postcode']); // post code to look up 
        $request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$postcodeTS1."&sensor=true";
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
        $status = $xml->status;
        if ($status=="OK") 
        {
   //request returned completed time to get lat / lang for storage
            $latTS1 = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
            $longTS1 = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
         }

  //insert into postcodes table for server side caching of lon lat

        $dateTS1= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $sqlinsert="INSERT INTO postcodestable (postcode,latitude,longitude, date_added) VALUES ('".$postcodeTS1."', '".$latTS1."', '".$longTS1."', '".$dateTS1."')";
        $sqlinserting = mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die(mysql_error());

  }

// we can now use $latTS1 and $longTS1 elsewhere within the HTML page

// we then run another script that removes all postcodes from Table where date_added is greater than 1 day.

?>
```

Comment: Client-side usually means using javascript to handle the calls. So, you'll need to add the request in your html/js rather than your server-side code

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and search for a geocode javascript then convert the variables into PHP.

I'm fine with php, but not javascript

Comment: That won't work to get around the over the limit issue. All PHP is executed on the server side. JS is run client-side (in the users's browser, not running on the server). GMaps 'knows' the difference.

Comment: Start here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding  There are some example code snippents available in the menu item Code Samples. It isn't terribly different to 'read' than PHP, you'll probably understand it.

Comment: So the approach is: 
Embed JS file with geocode script
Then get returned lon lat in JS file
Then convert the lon lat to a php variable
Then use php variables as usual....

Comment: I suppose you could. Keep in mind that the JS call will be asynchronous so you can't just run it in a serial fashion the way you would in PHP. You'll need to run the JS code and use ajax to call a php script (there are other ways, but that's usually my preferred way to handle JS->PHP calls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had a look around and compiled this...

```
<?php
    mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

    $sqlTS1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `postcodestable` WHERE `postcode` = UPPER('" . $_GET['postcode'] . "')");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sqlTS1)>0) {echo "postcode is already in database";}
else { $postcode1 = strtoupper($_GET['postcode']);
?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false;key=MYAPIKEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function GetLocation() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var postcode = <?php echo json_encode($postcodeTS1); ?>;;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': postcode }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        $.post("insert.php",
          { postcode1: postcode, lat1: latitude, long1: longitude },
             function(data){
             }
          );
            } else {
            }
        });
    };
    //-->

    window.onload = GetLocation;
    </script>

    <?php
echo "postcode is not in database"; }
?>
```

then I have the insert.php file which then inserts the postcode if it not in the database.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["postcode1"])) {
    mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
    $postcode2 = $_POST['postcode1'];
    $lat2 = $_POST['lat1'];
    $long2 = $_POST['long1'];
    $date2= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $sqlinsert="INSERT INTO postcodestable (postcode, latitude, longitude, date_added) VALUES ('".$postcode2."', '".$lat2."', '".$long2."', '".$date2."')";
        $sqlinserting = mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die(mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Elsewhere on the site, I clean up old postcodes if they are too old so as not to bloat my table.

```
<?php 
    mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM postcodestable WHERE date_added < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die( "An error has ocured: " .mysql_error (). ":" .mysql_errno ());
?>
```

That's about it... It works like a charm.

Thanks for the guidance.